# Как создать новый List<DataProperty2> из List<DataProperty1>?

Tags: android, kotlin, list, copy, dataclass

Есть `List<DataProperty1>`, где `DataProperty1`:

```
data class DataProperty1(
    @Json(name = "Property1")
    val property1: Int,

    @Json(name = "Property2")
    val property2: Int,

    @Json(name = "Property3")
    val property3: Int,
)
```

необходимо создать `List<DataProperty2>`, где `DataProperty2`:

```
data class DataProperty2(
     @Json(name = "Property4")
     val property4: Int,
    
     @Json(name = "Property5")
     val property5: Int
)
```

с указанием того, что данные `property4` необходимо заполнить из `property2`, а `property5` из `property1`.

Как правильно получить новый `List<DataProperty2>` с указанным условием?

Comment: list.map { DataProperty2(it.property2, it.property1) } https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, спасибо за помощь!